# Is there a way to override the avro version in Beam SDK java dependencies

Tags: apache-beam

I need avro version 1.11.0 in the below dependencies. Currently it is only supported in 1.8.2

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/beam/v2.38.0/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/apache/beam/gradle/BeamModulePlugin.groovy

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question. There are breaking changes in Avro so there is some tricky work to make Beam compatible with multiple versions at the same time. You can follow progress on https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-8388, https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/17372, https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/16271

Comment: Thanks for the above information. Will keep an eye on this